# Sending of emails after user's logout or browser closing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I should send e-mails to users immediately after logout or after closing of browser/browser tabs. Can you advise some cross-browser solution?

Comment: You need to send email from your server controller. Not from the browser. So what does cross browser solution mean?

Comment: Also consider the case if Power goes off.

Comment: @Lucky, I should track closing of browser, it's possible to do with help of javascript, so in this case I will need cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to send ajax query to your server:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   $.get('/controller_to_handle_action_mailer')
}
```

After that you'll need to create controller, which will send emails using ordinary `ActionMailer`.

Another good option is to add `websocket` connection. You'll need to explore `em-websocket` gem.

Just use this code:

```
EM.run {
  EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
    # code to sign in

    ws.onclose { ActionMailer.implement_it_stuff }
  end
}
```

Comment: It seems onbeforeunload doesn't work in Opera, some mobile browsers and old IE versions, so I think using of websockets will be more reliable. It's hard for me to choose between em-websocket, faye and activecable. Why do you choose  em-websocket?

Comment: Sergey, faye is outdated, actioncable (not activecable) isn't stable right now (I'm testing it). So, `em-websocket` is the best solution now. IMHO

Comment: actioncable will be build on top of faye-websocket, so I'm not sure it's outdated

Comment: You asked me about `faye`, not `faye-websocket`

Comment: Can you advise how I can access to rails classes (for example ActionMailer) in EM::WebSocket. As I understand it should be run as separate service.

Comment: `require_relative '../app/mailers/logout_mailer'` in the top of your eventmachine file

Comment: Mailer invokes model objects, thus I will need to require active_record and necessary model classes, also connection to database won't work from em-service. It seems it's too complicated solution for such simple service, is there easier way to solve this?

Comment: This is easy way. Of course, you can require whole rails environment to your em environment if you want

Comment: I think loading of whole rails environment makes sense in my case, thanks!